# Questions about probabilities with splitting a deck with jokers

Tags: probability

I attempted to solve the probability that when splitting a deck in half, you will have 1 or more jokers (meaning there would be 54 cards in the deck, 26 in split). My final answer was 39/53 or about 73.5%. What really confused me however, was how the process I used (listed below using the choose function) should technically be able to be applied to both players with a half-deck in their hand. How should the final probability be 73.5% for both players if that adds up to over 100%? I'm wondering if my process was wrong, or if I simply don't understand how probabilities work. My exact process was as follows:

P(1 or more Jokers in hand) = ((nCr(2,1) * nCr(52, 25)) + (ncR(2,2) * nCr(52,54))) / (nCr(54,26))

Comment: The events are not mutually exclusive, it is perfectly possible for *both* players to have one Joker.  Thus the probability can add to something greater than $1$.

Comment: Just as a sanity check:  The deck is large enough that it's not a bad approximation to imagine that the placement of the two Jokers are independent events.  Were that the case, then the probability that a fixed half gets $0$ Jokers is $\left(\frac 12\right)^2=\frac 14$.  Thus the answer should be very close to $1-\frac 14=\frac 34$.  Your $73.5\%$ looks perfectly sensible.

Comment: Actually, I take that back.  knowing that a given Joker is in a given half *increases* the probability that the other is in the other half (as there is one more empty slot in the other half).  Thus the answer should be slightly $>75\%$, not slightly less.  Indeed, the probability of getting $0$ Jokers is $\binom {52}{27}\big/ \binom {54}{27}=0.245283019$ so the answer you want is $0.754716981$.

Comment: I'm sorry but, what's the reasoning behind choosing 27 cards? There are still only ever 26 cards in one half, so I don't see how this number could have increased even with ruling out a card.

Comment: Half of $54$ is $27$

Comment: If you are discarding two cards prior to the split, you should say so. Of course, if the two cards are chosen randomly, that will slightly lower the probability, as you might discard one or both Jokers

Comment: Oh my god! I can't believe I made such a simple mistake. I meant for them to be included in the start, but got 52 and 54 mixed up. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

To start with there is a typo in your expression. I take it that "nCr(52,54)" was meant to be nCr(52,24) which yields $Pr \approx 73.58$ %

When computing for a **hand**, we treat the hand in isolation.

If you want the probability that there is at least one joker in the $52$ cards dealt, it is easier to do it using the complement

$Pr = 1 - \binom{52}{26}\binom{26}{26}/\binom{54}{26}\binom{28}{26} \approx 99.93$%

### Note

I have computed for hands of 26 each, if you want to compute for hands of 28, you know how to.

Comment: The OP described the problem incorrectly.  All $54$ cards in the deck, including the two jokers, are used.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: Very confusing.  OP's computation for a hand is for 26, and he questions how it has become 27 in Lulu's computation.

Comment: The last comment tipped me off to the OP's intentions.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig  i have added a note re 26/28